# How to capture Chrome DevTools Network requests payload data for post request using C# Selenium

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I need to capture browser's Network tab request payload data in case of post request or in case of Google Analytics tags validations using Selenium C#. So far I could validate some of the validation in request URL.

But I'm not able to capture selected request's payload data using class- DevToolsSessionDomains. Please refer attached snips for more insight.

I have already tried highlighted events, tasks in attached snip so far to achieve this objective but couldn't succeed.

[image]

Objective is to get Network request payload data as highlighted in below snip.

[image]